# Jboss 6.4 EAP to Jboss eap 7.2 migration ssl configuration issue

Tags: ssl, configuration, jboss, migration

I need to migrate the below configuration in JBoss 6.4 EAP to JBoss 7.2 EAP.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
  <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https8443"
     secure="true" max-post-size="25485760" max-connections="150">
<ssl name="test" password="test123" certificate-key-file = 
  "${jboss.server.config.dir}/certs/mycert.jks" protocol="TLSv1.1" ssl-protocol="TLS"/>
   </connector>
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
            <alias name="localhost"/>
            <alias name="example.com"/>
        </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```

How to migrate this configuration in undertow?.

Jboss EAP 7.2 has undertow instead of web and it supports listeners and not connectors.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I have same issue, Do You have any solution?